# Private fields are not Autowired in parent class when they have the same name as in child

Tags: java, spring, autowired

Let's say I have some lib that I can't modify. It has class that looks like this:

```
public class ClassFromLib {

    private Service service;

    public void mainActivity () {
        //some code
        service.doSomething();
        //some code
        secondaryActivity();
    }
    
    public void secondaryActivity() {
        //some code
        service.doSomething();
        //some code
    }

    @Required
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

And this class is configured as bean:

```
<bean id="classFromLibBean" class="ClassFromLib">
    <property name="service" ref="serviceImpl"/>
</bean>
```

I need to override `secondaryActivity` method of this class in my project. And I also need to use the same `service` that is private in the parent class. So, I created something similar to this:

```
public class MyClass extends ClassFromLib {

    private Service service;

    @Override
    public void secondaryActivity() {
        //some custom logic
        service.doSomething();
        //some custom logic
    }

    @Required
    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
}
```

And added bean configuration:

```
<bean id="myClassBean" class="MyClass">
    <property name="service" ref="serviceImpl"/>
</bean>
```

But when I'm getting my custom bean from application context and calling for `mainActivity` it returns `NullPointerException` because `service` field hasn't been initialized in the parent class and it is actually null. If I understand correctly, I have this issue because during bean initialization it calls for the child setter but ignores parent setter. I found WA: rename field and setter in the child class but this looks ugly. Is there any better solution?

Comment: You override the method because it has the same name and the same parameters, so it is expected to skip the parent class setter execution.
You can call the super in your child class overrides method.
@Required
    public void setService(Service service) {
        super.setService(service);
        this.service = service;
    }

Comment: @ЕмилиянЙорданов, thank you, this approach works

Answer (score 0):

Answer from ЕмилиянЙорданов helped me:

> You override the method because it has the same name and the same
> parameters, so it is expected to skip the parent class setter
> execution. You can call the super in your child class overrides
> method. @Required public void setService(Service service) {
> super.setService(service); this.service = service; }